# How to return to a view from controller after an Api call Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, laravel-blade

I have to make an API call for updating cart ,but after updating it doesn't render into payment page from controller index function

API.PHP

```
Route::post('cart',[Controller::class, 'index']);
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
// updating values 
return view('payment');
}
```

WEB.PHP file

```
Route::get('/payment', function () {
    return view('payment');
});
```

Comment: I guess you need to redirect to payment page `redirect()->route('/payment')` in `index` method. Can you try this approach?

Comment: You wouldn't return a view from an API call. You would return a response containing a success or failure message and perform the appropriate action based on the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the response first coming from API. Based on the response, you can do activities. In your case, you can use the below approach.

```
public function index(){
 try {
    //$response = API::functionName($requestData);
    if ($response === 'success') {
        //redirect to payment page
    } else {
        //same page with error message;
    }
 } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    dd($th->__toString());
 }
}
```

Comment: only issue is for redirection command. Rest of all are ok

Comment: Are you using `Ajax`?if yes, then you need to handle response check and use `window.location.href="/payment"`. if not using `Ajax` then put this code in index method `redirect()->route('/payment')`;